# How can i put a small subview on a view xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

i have a button in my  view and i want that  when user pushed it a small view should apper on it. there is two image about what i want.
[on this view-->](http://e1203.hizliresim.com/v/m/3nz51.png)

[this view](http://e1203.hizliresim.com/v/m/3nz6c.png)

How can i do tahat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up the small view as a top-level object in IB (that is, outside any view controller's view) and connect an outlet to refer to it, or set it up programmatically.

Then, in the action method for your button press, add that view as a subview of your view controller's view.

See the [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:
1. Create a custome view "this view".
2. On  click of a button call
    - [self.view addSubview:thisview] if just to show the view over the last view.
    - [self.view presentViewController:thisview animated:Yes]
3. To remove the view:
    [self.view removeFromParentViewController]